# Why does jquery seemingly interfere with simple background image

Tags: jquery, html

If the commented-out jquery library is instead included, the div no longer shows the background image.  How do I fix this, so I can use this jquery library?

[This works, no jquery](http://www.allwhole.com/t.html)

[This DOES NOT WORK (with jquery)](http://www.allwhole.com/t2.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>All Whole</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
 <!-- script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 
 <style>
    body, html {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
       }

     .fullScreenImage {
        background-image: url('i1.jpg');
        height: 100%; 
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
     }
</style>

  </head>
  <body>  
     <div  class="fullScreenImage"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... how are these related?

Comment: ill include links to try in description

Comment: jquery-mobile relies on jquery to work. You can see the error message in your first link: _"Cannot set property 'mobile' of undefined"_. When jquery-mobile **does work** (as in your second link), it changes the markup of the page and your `<div>` ends up with `0` height because the element it's within has no `height` specified

Comment: The resulting markup in your second link is different from the markup in your first link. I presume this is part of the jQuery mobile defaults, changing the page structure to help with mobile in some way. But at any rate, it's a CSS issue. Your background image is still there, but the div it's on is zero pixels tall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is not for jQuery but jQuery mobile plugin. jQuery mobile depend on jQuery library. So when you including library then jQuery mobile plugin activate then plugin adding own CSS role etc for body and crating other wrapper div etc. See in source code adding in body mobile view port related selector ui-`mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a` and your div also wrapped by `data-role="page"` that's why you loosing your actual expectation.

You should add following CSS if your screens show full height width:

```
.fullScreenImage {
    background-image: url(/i/welcome/i1.jpg);
    height: 100vh; //  Changed line
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help -- what's the difference for 100vh, the image does appear to change location when it can't fill the screen?

Comment: 100vh means 100% of view height of screens.

Comment: @Hanif You might want to change that last comment of yours, as it is "browser viewport", not "screen". In full screen the result is the same though, but an incorrect way to explain what `vh` means, where `vh` stands for "viewport height".